# C++: pow() optimizations with two constants

Tags: c++, optimization, pow

Simple question: When the compiler faces a call to, say, pow() with **two constants** (i.e. values from macros), is it optimized by evaluating it at compile time, or is it still calculated at run-time?

Example:

```
#define V_BITMEM_GRID 3
#define V_BITMEM_TOTAL pow(V_BITMEM_GRID,2)
```

Thanks!

**EDIT** If not, is there a way to calculate the square/cube of a macro as another macro (like I'm attempting above) at compile-time?

Comment: This will be compiler-dependent.  You could take a look at the assembler code that your compiler generates.

Comment: Template meta programming would do the job if your compiler's optimiser doesn't evaluate pow at runtime

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - template meta programming? I'll have to look into that. These macros are used in several loops and a call to pow() would be pretty strenuous.

Comment: If you're interested in only square/cube of the constant, I believe pretty much all compilers will evaluate something like this at compile-time: `#define V_BITMEM_GRID 3` `#define V_BITMEM_TOTAL V_BITMEM_GRID * V_BITMEM_GRID`.  In this case, there's no function call but a straight-forward math operator with constant values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be both. It depends on how intrusive the compiler is, whether it has access to the function implementation and can correctly evaluate it. There's no rule that specifies how it's supposed to be, as long as observed behavior is the same.

For example, I got the following:

```
#define X 1
#define Y 2
int foo(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << foo(X,Y);
00BE1000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (0BE203Ch)] 
00BE1006  push        3    
00BE1008  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (0BE2038h)] 
}
```

The function, as you can see, isn't even called. So it is possible that the call is eliminated for good.

Comment: This answers my question just fine. I'll have to toy with vs2008 to figure out how to get the output, but I didn't think about doing this at all!

Comment: @Di-0xide while in debug, right click and select "show dissasembly"

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't depend on it. A macro based approach is:

```
#define POW1(x) (x)
#define POW2(x) ((x)*(x))
#define POW3(x) (POW2(x)*POW1(x))
...
#define POW(x, y) POW##y(x)
```

Comment: If `x` is not a constant expression, this is potentially *far worse* than an optimized integral power function, though!

Answer (score 0):

gcc counts such expressions at compilation time, e.g.

Comment: Maybe your answer is missing the final part? ;)